# Running a bash job within a python script

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I was hoping for some advice on using the subprocess module.

I'm trying to run a bash job within a python script so my bash command (in the right directory) is: ./program myjob.inp

This is just running the executable "program" with myjob.inp being the input file (and my python script constantly updates myjob.inp).

I know that if I just wanted to run "program", I could do something like:

```
with open("tmp.dat","w") as fstore_tmp:
    subprocess.call(["./program"], stdout = fstore_tmp)
```

However, I can't figure out how to run the job taking in the input file myjob.inp such that it's doing the equivalent of ./program myjob.inp. I tried:

```
with open("tmp.dat","w") as fstore_tmp:
    subprocess.call(["./program", "myjob.inp"], stdout = fstore_tmp)
```

However, that doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `./program myjob.inp` is running within console? i.e. not in `python`?\

Comment: Yes so if I just wanted to run one iteration, I would do something like this from terminal: ./program myjob.inp which would run the "program" executable on my input file (myjob.inp). However because I'm updating myjob.inp and running the executable on it many times, I wrote a python script that will do this update automatically. When I run the python script, it will update myjob.inp and then I would like it to do the equivalent in bash of ./program myjob.inp. I know subprocess.call will do "./program" but I can't figure out how to put the whole command where it's doing this on the input file.

Comment: you need to use a pipe, read about `Popen` in the library documentation.

Comment: From looking at this, does Popen take arguments the way I describe in my opening post, i.e. I could just do subprocess.Popen(["./program", "myjob.inp"], stdout = PIPE])?

Comment: i did not work out what you need to do for your goal.  i just know that `subprocess.call` is insufficient.